# Change password through GeoServer REST API - previous password keeps working

Tags: geoserver

I am attempting to update the (default) admin password after startup of GeoServer using the REST API:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --user admin:geoserver \
  --data '{ "newPassword":"geoserver2" }' \
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/self/password
```

This seems to work fine; I am able to log into the admin UI using the new password. There seems  however that the previous password (`geoserver`) still works in subsequent REST API calls. The same thing happens if I change it again; now all three passwords works! I'v also attempted to call the `/reaload` endpoint, to no avail. (The previous passwords does not work for the admin UI.) Whats going on? Something cached somewhere?

```
# rest.properties
/**;GET,POST,PUT,DELETE=ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR
```

Version: 2.18.0, docker, tomcat:9-jdk11-openjdk

Edit: Same thing happens when chaning password using the admin interface, `geoserver` still works for REST calls.

**Log output**:

````
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [security.xml] - Successful lock: security/usergroup/default/users.xml.lock
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start storing user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Storing user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:18 INFO [geoserver.rest] - Changed password for user admin
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [platform.resource] - Notifying ENTRY_MODIFY change on /var/local/geoserver/security/usergroup/default/users.xml. Created: 0, removed: 0, modified: 0
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Start reloading user/groups for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Reloading user/groups successful for service named default
05 Feb 08:07:22 INFO [geoserver.security] - Adjusted last modified for file: security/usergroup/default/users.xml
```
````